# French children's book with a cat turned into a deer

Tags: identification-request, french-language

I'm trying to remember the title of a children's book that I read when I was a kid in the late 90s, in French.
The year must have been about 97 or 98, not later than 99-2000.

The only thing I can remember distinctly is the main story: it was about an anthropomorphic cat (as in, it was dressed, lived in a house, etc., human-like animals like in a lot of children's books) that got struck by a sort of a spell or a hex that changed it slowly into a deer. I remember there was something likely about a magical forest of sort. and the cat was very scared and worried by this transformation, it started getting deer antlers and everything. One thing that I really remember because I felt it was so sad, when I read it as a kid, is the cat crying that it was now having to leave its house. This was because as a deer, it would have to live in the forest, and it was very sad to leave its house.

I remember it as a rather "dark" or, let's say, sad story (I was like 6 or 7, so pretty easy to find anything dark or sad at this age).

I also think I remember that the story had a happy ending, that the cat got back into a cat form and was happy, and everything. Likely it was some "karma thing" that the cat had done that came to punish it and teach it a lesson, but in the end things turned well. I'm not completely sure about this part, though.

Comment: Welcome to Literature Stack Exchange, take our [tour]! Please look at the [identification-request wiki](https://literature.stackexchange.com/tags/identification-request/info) and, if any of the prompts jog your memory, please [edit] your question with further details. For example, what style were the illustrations (colorful, line drawings, cartoony, etc.?) What was on the cover? In what context did you read the book (in school, from grandparent's closet, a birthday present, etc.?) How large was the book, both thickness and cover area? Any details may help us narrow down the search.